# Telnet is not recognized as internal or external command, even after activation

Tags: tcp, windows-7

I am trying to perform port forwarding to connect two emulators using TCP protocol on Windows.
Although I have enabled TCP client program from control Panel, "telnet" command is not recognized in Command Prompt.
Could anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 470, accepted):

You have to go to Control Panel>Programs>Turn Windows features on or off. Then, check "Telnet Client" and save the changes. You might have to wait about a few minutes before the change could take effect.

Comment: Or just type "Windows features" in the search box

Comment: I had to reboot after activation, so if it's still not working, try a reboot.

Answer (score 88):

1. Open "Start" (Windows Button)
2. Search for "Turn Windows features On or Off"
3. Check "Telnet client" and check "Telnet server".

Comment: Why are you enabling Telnet server ? Isn't client enough for this question ?

Answer (score 46):

You can also try **`dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:TelnetClient`**

Run this command with "Run as an administrator"

[Reference](http://tweaks.com/windows/48535/how-to-install-telnet-with-only-one-command/)

Comment: In my case the "Telnet client" was already checked in "Windows Features". Running this dism command worked like a charm to restore functionality - thanks!

Comment: This was the only way that worked for me, as selecting "Turn Windows features On or Off" kept opening Server Manager, which didn't have the option of enabling the telnet client.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using [Putty](http://www.putty.org/) (freeware). It is mainly known as a SSH client, but you can use for Telnet login as well

Answer (score 4):

If your Windows 7 machine is a member of an AD, or if you have UAC enabled, or if security policies are in effect, telnet more often than not must be run as an admin. The easiest way to do this is as follows

1. Create a shortcut that calls cmd.exe
2. Go to the shortcut's properties
3. Click on the Advanced button
4. Check the "Run as an administrator" checkbox

   After these steps you're all set and telnet should work now.

Comment: are you sure? The command "telnet" in disabled by defualt in windows.