# Pairing Android emulator and Android Wear emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, wear-os

I've been looking for information about this for a while and I can't seem to find anything.

Short story is, I have the Android L Preview emulator running and the Android Wear emulator.  Im only using Android L since the 4.4.2 image's don't support Android Wear to my knowledge.

The issue I have is that Play Services don't appear to exist, or need updating on these images so I can't connect the emulators.

Has anyone got this working?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205888/pairing-android-emulator-with-wear-emulator ;)

Comment: That's 4.3, and I don't believe Android Wear supports 4.3 at the moment, hence my question :)

Comment: Android Wear supports all devices running Android 4.3 and up. (4.3 added the Bluetooth LE support that's mainly why)

Comment: Google APIs for Android L is not released yet. Hence no support for Play services. This is not currently supported

Comment: **Quick note:** Contrary to my assumption it's possible to connect a `smartphone-emulator` (4.4.2) to a `wear-emulator`. See the Linked StackOverflow-Post.