# Pair Wear Emulator with Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I'm sure this is a simple question, but I seem to be spinning my wheels here.  I want to connect and android wear device (emulated) with and android device (also emulated).  I've tried port forwarding but that doesn't seem to do the trick for me.  Does anyone have any good documentation for this?

Comment: You can find answer from SO. SO rocks!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205888/pairing-android-emulator-with-wear-emulator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pairing Android and Wear emulators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205888/pairing-android-and-wear-emulators)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Genymotion + Wear Emulator

1. [Download](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download) and install genymotion image 4.3+;
2. [Download](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps) Gapps for the selected version of the image;
3. [Install](http://geocoding.io/2014/10/installing-google-apps-in-genymotion/) gapps in genymotion and [configure](http://geocoding.io/2014/10/installing-google-apps-in-genymotion/);
4. [Download](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/android-wear/) and install Android Wear;
5. Launch the wear emulator;
6. Set port forward from genymotion to wear:

   ```
   adb -s {genimotion_ip}:{genimotion_port} -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601
   ```
7. Use!

Comment: Tested on Android 5.1.0 Genymotion Nexus 5 and Android Wear 1.4 and it works

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that if you want to pair to an Android Wear emulator, you have to tell the Android Wear connecting app to "Connect to Emulator".

I think that might be the missing step from the below comment - you have to make sure to tell the app to connect to the emulator. Then it will use the port forwarded adb stuff.