# Pair Android and Wear emulators with Android 5+

Tags: android, android-emulator, wear-os

I trying connect two emulators, but Android Wear App stay in "Connecting..." state.

I read many manuals about connection with emulators and doing same as read

[Pairing Android and Wear emulators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205888/pairing-android-and-wear-emulators)

[Pair Wear Emulator with Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27662933/pair-wear-emulator-with-android-emulator)

Doing (Install Wear App, Forwarding ports and etc)  except for one difference -> wear emulator 4.4w not started and i using wear emulator with Android 5+.

I trying do it with Pure Android Emulator, Genymotion, BlueStacks and have same result.

I think those manuals are obsolete.

Anybody can connect to new android wear with android 5,5.1,6,7?

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Based from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205888/pairing-android-and-wear-emulators), using an emulated Android device connected to a Wear emulator is not supported. You must have atleast one real device, android device or android wear. Please check the Official Android Wear page here: https://developer.android.com/training/building-wearables.html