# Status Code 16 when creating new GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, google-api-client

I am trying to create a basic wearable app which accepts new bitmaps from the main android application.  Unfortunately, when I try to .build() the GoogleApiClient I the connection failed listener is called with an error code 16.

This is the exact error received from the ConnectionFailedListener

> 03-21 13:36:35.903    3089-3089/com.example.android.wearable.watchface
>   D/Watch Face Config﹕ onConnectionFailed:
>   ConnectionResult{statusCode=unknown status code 16, resolution=null}

---

App Code:

```
        // create the api client to allow sending information to the wearable
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onConnected: " + connectionHint);
                    // Now you can use the Data Layer API
                }
                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended: " + cause);
                }
            })
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: " + result);
                }
            })
                    // Request access only to the Wearable API
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .build();
```

---

In the wearable app I have a DataListenerService created, but it doesn't matter at the moment because the API is not build correctly.

Thanks for any assistance or comments!!

UPDATE - I changed the emulator device target from **Google APIs** to **Android 5.0.1** and the error changed to:

> 03-21 14:18:24.620    3025-3025/com.example.android.wearable.watchface
>   D/Watch Face Config﹕ onConnectionFailed:
>   ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_MISSING, resolution=null}

UPDATE 2 - Found [this](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) article and followed the instructions.  Then my app failed to compile.  After that I went to the SDK manager based on the marked answers suggest and checked Google Play Services (they were not installed).  Now the app builds but still gives the SERVICE_MISSING error above.

Comment: Do you have Android Wear installed on your phone?

Comment: I'm using an emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have Google Play Services and [Android Wear app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.wearable.app) installed on your device to use the Wearable API. By default, emulators don't have it, so either install it manually, or use a device that has it on board already.

If you're using Genymotion, simply [download Google Play Services](https://goo.im/gapps/) and drag & drop on the emulator. Then sign in with your Google account and use Play Store to download the Android Wear app.

More info [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-install-google-play-services-on-android-emulator-genymotion/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su).

If you're **not** using Genymotion, you should start doing it now as it's much faster than standard AVDs.

Just remember, while this will allow your `GoogleApiClient` to connect successfully, you'll still have to establish a connection between the emulator and your wearable device (or wearable emulator) if you want to make a real use of the Wearable API. So please refer to other questions on how to create or simulate a bluetooth connection, [for example this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205888/pairing-android-emulator-with-wear-emulator).

Edit: official Android emulators are nowadays much faster & have Google Play Services installed out of the box.

Comment: do you have any direction on how to install the Wear App inside the Emulator?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this SO question:

[Android Wear - Unexpected error code 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669520/android-wear-unexpected-error-code-16/29669521)

I had a similar problem. The error code is telling you that the Android wear app is not installed. In your onConnectionFailedListener you need to add something like:

```
// Connection failed listener method for a client that only
// requests access to the Wearable API
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (result.getErrorCode() == ConnectionResult.API_UNAVAILABLE) {
    // The Android Wear app is not installed
    }
    ...
}
```

From here:

https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html#Starting

"Access the Wearable API"