# How connect wear emulator and phone emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I have the following virtual devices:

- android wear: Android 4.4W.2
- android phone: Android 5.0.1

Is it possible to connect them? If so, how?
Thanking you in advance

Comment: You can connect your real device with Watch AVD via wireless
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59829589/8115083

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so simple, but I think this answer may help you (as helped me):

[Pairing Android Emulator with Wear Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205888/pairing-android-emulator-with-wear-emulator/25506889#25506889)