# Cannot sync account with smartphone using android wear emulator

Tags: android, google-play-services, emulation, wear-os

for my wear project, i'm setting up the android wear emulator (Nougat) following the official developer guide:

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html#set-up-emulator

After forwarding the communication using `adb -d forward`, the emulator is seen by Android Wear App installed in my Honor 8 smartphone.

Nevertheless, when I try to sync my google account (step 9 of the guide), the app hangs in the "trying to sync" screen for hours.

I need to pair the emulator with my smartphone because I need to use GPS coordinates into my wear app.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Can you share the logs? While you're at it, try reading this related SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25506889/5995040)

Comment: Which tad do i have to search?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by wipe the emulator's data

So try to:

1)Wipe data in Android studio's Virtual device manager

2)Clear data of your android wear app on the phone

3)Pair the emulator again

4)Sync the account on Android Wear app on your phone instead of in the emulator