# Can I connect a physical Wear OS device to an emulated Android device?

Tags: android, debugging, adb, wear-os

I've found [this official guide](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/debugging#enable-dev-options) that looks like it's what I need, but I'm not sure how to then connect it to an emulated Android device.

For context, I've been following [this guide](https://medium.com/mindorks/a-beginner-guide-to-android-watch-app-wear-2-0-71b27a802d11) to adding a simple Wear OS module to my project. I don't have a physical Android device easily available, but I do have a Wear OS device.

Is this possible? Or should I try [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25506889/7492795) of linking two emulated devices?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no easy way to do that. 
Usually the connection goes in the opposite direction, 
you pair physical phone with wear emulator.

Although I have found this article where an author pairs wear and phone emulators.
https://www.nindoda.com/pair-your-android-phone-emulator-to-android-wear-emulator-with-android-studio/
If this is possible, probably you might use similar solution to pair wear device to phone emulator.

Remember that you can also pair your android wear device with iOS.