# How do I pair a physical Wear OS device with a virtual phone in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, wear-os

I was wondering if it is actually possible to pair a physical Wear OS device to a virtual android phone in Android Studio. I am currently developing a fitness app that makes use of the Health Service API, but because it is only compatible with Android 11+ I cannot use a physical phone (my phone runs Android 10 and isn't updateable) to run the corresponding companion app on. Additionally a virtual wear OS device cannot be used because the emulator doesn't as of yet have support for an exercise type I am interested in (no weightlifting category - [see here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/health-services/synthetic-data#dependencies)).

Essentially this means I require my companion app to run on my physical watch (a Galaxy Watch 5 running Wear OS 3.5) and the phone app to run virtually in the Android Studio emulator (a Pixel 4 running Android 12) and have them communicate. I recently attempted to have my physical watch pair with the virtual phone using Android Studio's Wear OS Pairing Assistant feature but was unable to - with Android Studio saying "Wear OS pairing assistant cannot pair unsupported devices" [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wBUB.png).

When checking the documentation for pairing wearables and devices it doesn't seem there is any information on pairing a virtual phone with a physical watch, the only instructions I find are about [connecting a physical phone to a watch emulator](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/get-started/creating#pair) . I understand that Wear OS 3 is [not compatible](https://support.google.com/wearos/answer/9266307?hl=en-GB&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid) with the Wear OS app, and this app seems to be needed when attempting to pair a watch [through the phone emulator](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/get-started/creating#pair-phone-with-avd). This is a summary of what I tried:

- Attempted to pair my Watch 5 to the virtual Pixel 4 using Android Studio's 'Pair Wearable' in the Device Manager tab
- Attempted to pair using the Pixel 4's Wear OS app but couldn't see the watch and only had the option to 'Pair with emulator'

I was wondering if there is any way in Android Studio or (perhaps a command in adb) that would allow me to pair my physical watch to the virtual phone. This question was asked a little while back [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55841915/can-i-connect-a-physical-wear-os-device-to-an-emulated-android-device) but I wondered if there had been any updates? Thanks :)

Comment: The Samsung watch should pair with [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.app.watchmanager) companion app, you should try to download it to the Pixel 4 emulator and try to pair

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried downloading the Samsung companion app in the Pixel emulator and it didn't see the Watch unfortunately. I believe this is a consequence of the emulator [not supporting Bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604305/how-to-use-android-emulator-for-testing-bluetooth-application) which perhaps might explain why the wearable app didn't see my Watch 5. A possible solution might be using a virtual machine that utilises the host computer's Bluetooth and using the Samsung companion app to connect to the watch :)

Answer (score 0):

Your emulator needs to setup to use your PC's Bluetooth in order to discover your physical WearOS device.