# Unable to pair wear emulator

Tags: android, emulation

I'm trying to write an App for SmartWatch. In order to get some data from Internet I want to write a complementary App for phone.
Now the problem: I have to pair the wear emulator with the phone emulator.
I tryed the solutions given on [Pairing Android and Wear emulators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205888/pairing-android-and-wear-emulators) but it always **not** works and stucks saying "Emulator Connecting...".

I tried with my real phone, too (using https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/49586/how-do-i-connect-an-android-wear-emulator-to-a-real-phone/), with the same result...

I really don't know anymore what can I do.
Can someone help me?

Thanks
Luca

Comment: Have you seen the official docs on this? https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating also, maybe it's not relevant to your app but you can fetch data from the internet as standalone app.

Comment: Hi. Yes, I see it. And it says nothing more than other tutorials... :( And since my SmartWatch has just Android 6, I can't access the internet directly...